# "Czar" vs "tsar" - origins and pronunciation

Tags: orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, loanwords, variants

How did the word come into English with the two variants *czar* and *tsar*?
The 'ts' spelling is a transliteration of the Russian 'царь', but the 'cz' spelling is what interests me more. To me it looks Polish, where 'cz' is common, but is pronounced as English 'ch'. Where did this second form come from?

Comment: 'tsar' and 'czar' are pronounced identically in English /zar/.

Comment: While pronounced identically, the metaphorical ones, i.e. governmental officials with supra-departmental responsibilities— are invariably *czar* in the U.S.: *AIDS czar*, *counterterrorism czar*, *drug czar*. The British seem to accept *tsar* for both types: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/politics/conservative/9550058/Coalition-has-created-more-policy-tsars-than-Tony-Blair.html .

Comment: I agree with Ray. When I was younger the common use was "Czar". In fact, I have since wondered why it has been "changed" to "Tsar".

Comment: @Mitch: Also /tsar/, depending on where you're from (the OED lists both)

Comment: @Matt: I disagree with the OED then. Word initial /ts/ is not in the repertoire of any variety of native English. Many native English speakers are able to pronounce it but not in any native English word.

Comment: @Mitch: I'm a native (British) English speaker, and I've always pronounced it /tsar/. Disagreeing with the OED on matters of how English is used in practice is a brave (and usually foolish) thing to do - particularly when you are asserting that something **never** happens. Also I don't know where you got the notion that word-prefix /ts/ doesn't exist. We also have tsunami: (both /tso͞oˈnämē/ and  /so͞oˈnämē/)

Comment: @Matt: I consider the OED the absolute best reference compared to any other. But it's not perfect and it can be very misleading. I guess that you are one of the few who can pronounce closer to the original articulation for 'tse-tse fly', but those three words are about it. Initial consonant clusters beyond 'str' are rare in English. Any others, like the 'kv' in 'kvetch' are only found in small subcultures.

Comment: In Polish, it's "Car". "Czar" would be read as "Char" as in "Charge". The whole problem stems from English abusing 'c' as 'k' leaving the language without fully functional 'c' and substituting various 'ts','cz', 'tz', 'z' etc.

Comment: @Mitch Not sure what you mean about initial consonant clusters—English has a large inventory of them! Almost any combination of non-homorganic (sibilant +) plosive/fricative + liquid is allowed. /ts/ isn't even really a cluster—it's just an affricate, like /ch/. It doesn't exist in any native words, no… but that doesn't make it hard to pronounce. /sk/ doesn't exist in native words, either, and no one has trouble with that.

Comment: @Mitch I agree with your statement about consonant clutsters in English, but I also agree with that these are rare as a "natural" occurance in English, usually being loan words from other languages. But in most languages the onset (word initial) cluster usually represents a single sound. When a "tz" like sound is  borrowed these will often borrow as much of the borrowing languages orthography as possible, so the varaiation of a single word in it's spelling not as extreme as its pronunciation. Of course a French loan word will likely not be pronounced like a German loan word regardless.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm curious what you meant by saying that (word-initial) /sk/ doesn't occur in native (English) words.

Comment: @SF why is that abuse?  /k/ is the original value of Latin C, after all.

Comment: @tchrist /sk/ became /ʃ/ at some point before Old English. All words that contain /sk/ in Modern English are either borrowed later on or onomatopoeic (like _tsk tsk_). Although I believe the change was not quite consistent throughout the dialects/languages at the time with /skr/, so there may be one or two words in /skr/ that are actually completely inherited.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks. You know, I came close to offering the OE *scip* example for a skiff/skip (now *ship*) but didn't want to prime you in case you were meaning something else.

Comment: @phoog: Latin has some very consistent rules as to when 'c' is pronounced as 'k' and when as 'ts' and while the rule *seems* to be really narrow ('c' followed by any of 'y','i','e') the number of words where it's applicable seems to nearly outweigh the number of words where it isn't.

Comment: @SF. In my experience, classicists pronounce "c" always as /k/.  For example "cibo" is /kibo/.  In the church, "soft" c's are pronounced as in Italian, like the "ch" in English "church".  I have only encountered c as /ts/ in German and in the Slavic languages, whose Latin orthography is quite likely derived from German.

Comment: @phoog: Cicero?

Comment: @SF. Wikipedia gives [ˈkɪ.kɛ.roː]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cicero

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet you seem to be confusing genetically native words with the phonetic repertoire of native speakers.  Words like skirt and task are fully naturalized in English and /sk/ is an integral part of the English phonetic system, unlike /ts/ in the initial position.  (And what do you mean by "borrowed later on"?  Such words were absorbed in Old English.)

Comment: @phoog The Old English period _was_ later on. The /sk/ → /ʃ/ change happened at some point between Common West Germanic and Old English. I wasn’t actually confusing genetic association with phonetic repertoire, just pointing out that at least to some people (myself included) /ts/ is **also** fully naturalised in English. All words that begin in /ts/ and /sk/ are loan words—the only difference between them is that the latter group is much larger and has much _older_ loan words. But /ts/ is as naturalised to me as /kv/ is, i.e., completely naturalised, but rare.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet if I have to resort to tricks to get a native English speaker to pronounce word-initial /ts/ when singing in German, which I have had to do, that says to me that word-initial /ts/ is not normal.  Clearly at any rate initial /sk/ and initial /ts/ have *some* different status in English, whatever label you want to put on it.  I understand that sk to sh happened before OE, which is why the borrowing of sk- words *during OE* left us with sk- words in modern English. Sk may have left the language beforehand, but it returned soon thereafter and stayed.

Comment: @phoog No arguments there (I’ve met many English-speakers as well who had trouble with initial ⟨z⟩ in German because they for some reason can’t pronounce initial /ts/). My initial beef was simply with Mitch’s overly broad statement that “/ts/ is not in the repertoire of any variety of native English”—it may not be for a lot of people, but it is for a lot of people, too.

Answer (score 12):

Here’s what the OED says:

> The Slavonic word ultimately represents Latin *Cæsar*, but came . . .
>   through the medium of a Germanic language in which the word had the
>   general sense ‘emperor’ . . . The spelling with *cz-* is against the
>   usage of all Slavonic languages; the word was so spelt by . . . the
>   chief early source of knowledge as to Russia in Western Europe, whence
>   it passed into the Western Languages generally; in some of these it is
>   now old-fashioned; the usual German form is now *zar* ; French adopted
>   *tsar* during the 19th cent. This also became frequent in English
>   towards the end of that century, having been adopted by the Times
>   newspaper as the most suitable English spelling.

Comment: [This NGram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/ngrams/graph?content=czar%2Ctsar&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows how *tsar* came to be the dominant spelling almost a century ago, confirming my suspicion that *czar* is the older version. It's probably only been used at all in recent decades to deliberately evoke the sense of talking about something *very* long ago.

Comment: According to COCA, czar is the dominant spelling.  As in *drug czar*.  I doubt that's meant to evoke anything resembling Tsarist Russia.

Comment: -1 Also I'm sorry but I doubt this is 'fair use' of the OED given that it is entirely copy-pasted.

Comment: [The Guardian](http://www.guardian.co.uk/styleguide/t) newspaper style guide says `tsar
not czar. Avoid "the government's transport tsar" or other PR-generated nonsense`

Comment: @z7ss: *drug czar* is a highly idiomastic usage that's [shot to prominence](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/ngrams/graph?content=drug+czar%2Cdrug+tsar&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) in the last couple of decades. But even though that particular one goes against the trend, the fact is that [tsar has been twice as common as czar](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/ngrams/graph?content=czar%2Ctsar&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) for at least half a century.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The 'fact', is that czar is currently the dominant spelling and that is according to a *balanced* corpus, not google books.  The Guardian Style Guide cannot simply prescribe otherwise.  I suggest people who agree with your original and erroneous comment on the usage of *czar* search this corpus for themselves.

Comment: @z7ss: I showed you what I got from NGrams, which is a couple of million written instances, and which agrees with my gut feel. [Here](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/ngrams/graph?content=czar%2Ctsar&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) is the picture over 250 years. *Czar* is more common in total, but definitely not over the last 50 years. If you have different data, let's see it.

Comment: @z7sgѪ: Certainly in UK newspapers (which *love* the word *tsar* meaning "a government official with responsibility in a specific domain") *tsar* is the spelling I always see; never *czar*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Case matters here, since both "Czar" and "Tsar" are [much more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=czar%2Ctsar%2CCzar%2CTsar&year_start=1800) than the lowercase versions.  And in the "English One Million (2009)" corpus, "Czar" has actually [overtaken](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=czar%2Ctsar%2CCzar%2CTsar&year_start=1800&corpus=1) "Tsar" in the last few year, although lowercase "tsar" is still slightly more common than "czar".

Comment: @z7sgѪ COCA shows that _czar_ is more common than _tsar_ in AmE by about 5:1 overall, but it also shows that _czar_ is decreasing while _tsar_ is increasing (since 2010, the ratio is about 3:2). It also shows that the vast majority of _czar_’s are the figurative type (drug czars being especially common), and if we attempt to roughly discount those by searching instead for _the [cz|ts]ar_, the ratio is less than 2:1 overall, and _tsar_ has in fact been **more common** since around 2005. So your claim that _czar_ is “currently the dominant spelling” is not quite borne out by COCA.

Answer (score 7):

***Origin of 'czar' and 'tsar'***

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) lists *czar* as the primary spelling in U.S. English, and *tsar* as a variant spelling. *Webster's Word Histories* (1989), in a fairly detailed discussion of the two spellings, attributes the spelling *czar* to a sixteenth-century Austrian baron:

> **czar** *Czar*, or *tsar*, is our English word for a pre-Soviet Russian emperor. *Tsar* is a straightforward borrowing from the Russian, but the form of *czar* is strange. It looks rather like a Polish word, and in fact there is a Polish *czar*, but it is pronounced like English *char* and means 'charm' or 'spell'. The Polish equivalent of Russian *tsar* is spelled *car*—Polish *c* is pronounced *ts*. We owe our peculiar spelling of *czar* to an Austrian diplomatist, Siegmund, Freiherr (Baron) von Herberstein (1486–1566). ... Herberstein wrote in Latin, but his spelling of Russian *tsar* was influenced by his native German. The *c* in Herberstein's *czar* may have come from Polish, but his *z* was surely added as a pronunciation indicator—*z* in German, like *c* in Polish, is pronounced *ts*. The English word *czar* first appeared in a 1555 translation of Herberstein's work [*Rerum moscovitarum commentarii*, or *Commentaries on Muscovite Matters*].

The entry for the term in John Ayto, *Arcade Dictionary of Word Origins* (1990) focuses exclusively on the derivation of the spelling *tsar*:

> **tsar** *Caesar* was a Roman cognomen (English gets *caesarian* from it) and from the days of Augustus was used as part of the title of 'emperor.' The Germanic peoples took it over in this sense (it is the source of German *kaiser*) and passed it on to prehistoric Slavic as *tsēsari*. This has evolved into Serbo-Croat and Bulgarian *tsar* and Russian *tsar'*—source of English *tsar*.

---

***British and U.S. preferences for 'tsar' versus 'czar'***

The question of whether *tsar* or *czar* should be viewed as the primary spelling in English is a matter of contention, as various answers and comments here indicate. Robert Hendrickson, *The Facts on File Encyclopedia of Word and Phrase Origins* (1997) offers this remark at the end of its entry for *czar; tsar; tsarina; etc.*:

> Spelling of the word varies in both British and American dictionaries—neither form is accepted by all authorities in either country.

That the tendency of reference works to prefer *tsar* in UK English and *czar* in U.S. English is clear from the way the British and American versions of the OED handle the spelling. From *Concise Oxford English Dictionary*, revised tenth edition (2001)):

> **czar etc.** *n.* variant spelling of **TSAR** etc.

From *Oxford American Dictionary and Thesaurus* (2003):

> **tsar** var. of CZAR.

Bryan Garner, *Garner's Modern American Usage*, second edition (2003) comes out squarely in favor of the spelling *czar*:

> **czar; tsar.** The spelling *czar* is overwhelmingly predominant. *Tsar*, though closer to the Russian form, is archaic.

And so does *The Associated Press Stylebook and Briefing on Media Law* (2002):

> **tsar** Use *czar*.

The spelling *czar* no doubt also benefits in the United States from being identified as a probable typo under Microsoft Word's default U.S. spelling preferences.

And yet something very odd occurs when you run Google Books searches for *tsar* (red line) versus *czar* (blue line). The British English chart for the years 1809–2008 is not surprising, given the U.K. preference for *tsar*:

[image]

But the corresponding chart for American English is astonishing:

[image]

Despite being identified as the primary spelling by the Merriam-Webster, Oxford American, American Heritage, and Random House English dictionaries, *tsar* appears to have held its own against *czar* for the past century in the Google Books database of U.S. publications.

A usage note under the entry for *czar* in *The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, fourth edition (2000) offers perhaps the best explanation of this seeming anomaly:

> The word *czar* can also be spelled *tsar*. *Czar* is the most common form in American usage and the one nearly always employed in the extended senses "any tyrant" or  informally "one in authority." But *tsar* is preferred by most scholars of Slavic studies as a more accurate transliteration of the Russian and is often found in scholarly writing with reference to one of the Russian emperors.

To the extent that *tsar* continues to be at least as common as *czar* in U.S. books, *AHDEL* suggests, this may reflect the strong preference of Slavic studies authors for *tsar*. Presumably, if the Google Books database were to add newspapers and (more) magazines to its scanned holdings, the influence of Slavic studies scholars' preferences on the reported overall popularity of *tsar* versus *czar* in the United States would be much diminished.

Comment: Nice answer! Those ngram graphs look a little odd though  – I wonder if the low frequency of the word affects their reliability. Wikipedia says the "cz" digraph for /ts/ or derived sounds was once common across Europe. It is supposedly the source of the ç character. I remember when I was in Hungary, some place names used the digraph "cz" instead of the usual "c" to represent /ts/. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin-script_digraphs#C

Comment: @sumelic: Hi. The actual Ngram graphs that these charts are based on are as follows: [British English, 1809–2008](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=czar%2Ctsar&year_start=1809&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cczar%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctsar%3B%2Cc0); [American English, 1809–2008](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=czar%2Ctsar&year_start=1809&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cczar%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctsar%3B%2Cc0). I started at 1809 for 200 years of coverage—and to avoid a spike around 1806. My charts used no rounding.

Answer (score 4):

Czar is not the only older form...

In 17th century texts both **Czar** and  **Tzar** occurs. In this account of diplomacy from [1669](http://books.google.com/books?id=5GZUAAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=en#v=onepage&q&f=false) - *A Relation of Three Embassies From his Sacred Majestie Charles II* - : ***both forms occur***, 'the czar' [**5**](http://books.google.com/books?id=5GZUAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA26&dq=%22czar%22#v=onepage&q=%22czar%22&f=false) times and 'the tzar' [**56**](http://books.google.com/books?id=5GZUAAAAcAAJ&pg=PR16&dq=%22tzar%22) times

> But amongst all the Princes of *Europe*, that, by  their congratulations of his Re-establishment, seemed ardently to aspire at His Alliance, the *Tzar* of *Moscovy* had the most equitable pretentions.
>   ― p 2
>
> ..by *Moscovie* are ordinarily understood all the Provinces united under the Obedience of the *Czar*.
>   
> ―  p 26

'the Czar' occurs in 5 places between pages 26 and 47 while 'the Tzar' is the only form in the rest of the book, as well in the index. This might reflect the usage of two different writers..

'Tzar' is also used in a Swedish text from the same period:
Joh. Widekindi. ([1671](http://books.google.com/books?id=I95PAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA856&dq=Thet%20Swenska%20i%20Ryssland%20%22tzar%22)) Thet Swenska i Ryssland Tijo åhrs Krijgz-Historie:

> och then Store Herre Tzar och Storfurste Michael Fedorowitz
>   ― p 883
>   ...

As late as in *James Bell ([1850](http://books.google.com/books?id=Nw5QAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA26&dq=%22the%20tzar%22&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22the%20tzar%22&f=false)) A System of Geography, Popular and Scientific,* both Tzar and Czar occurs (5 times each)

and in *New Monthly Magazine* volume 78 ([1846](http://books.google.com/books?id=FtcRAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA24&dq=%22the%20tzar%22))

'the czar' twice (244, 245)
'the tzar' five times (p 26, 38, 31; 75, 90)
'the tsar' twice (31, 38) [A Summer in Russia Chap VI]

EDIT

It seems the spelling '**czar**' was first used by *Sigmund Freiherr von Herberstein* who was twice envoy of the Holy Roman Emperor to Russia. In 1549 life he published his notes about the lands he visited in ***Rerum Moscoviticarum Commentarii***.

> **Czar** Rhutenica lingua regem significat. cum autem communi Slavonica lingua, apud Polonos, Bohemos, & alios omnes sumpta quadam consonantia, ab ultima, & ea gravi quidem syllaba Czar, Imperator seu Caesar intelligatur
>   -p[18](http://books.google.com/books?id=AHxUAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18&dq=Czar%20Rhutenica%20lingua)

*von Herberstein spoke Slovenian*, so it might be fair to assume that spelling he used would be a *Slovenian approximation of word he heard (or read)*.

This is pure speculation on my part but maybe what he heard was some Russian pronounciation of OCS **цѣсарь**, perhaps [tsəsar]

Comment: I always thought *czar* or *csar* came about because of the *ae* in *Caesar* (often ligated). Nonnative speakers couldn't figure out how to pronounce it, so the ae was left out. The *s* in Caesar is pronounced as if it were *z* ... .

Answer (score 1):

The spelling 'czar' was almost universally used in the U.S. well into my adulthood.  I am now in my 80's.  During WWII we had various people in the government running imnportant programs who were dubbed 'czar' of their program, whether it had to do with manpower or some industry or price controls.  The word morphed into 'tsar', which my limited knowledge of Slavic languages would suggest is closer to the Russian, sometime later, probably gradually through the '50's to 70's--much more recently than a century ago.  I can recall noting the change and wondering why.  If the OED doesn't cite usage to indicate when the change took place, I don't know who would.

Comment: welcome to the Stack Exchange sites. While your answer (based on personal experience) is good, for questions like this we really appreciate answers that point to sources. In this case, perhaps there are some newspaper or magazine articles from the 1940's on that use czar/tsar would be helpful in backing up your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I live in America, where the "Czar" spelling was commonly used into my adulthood - in the late 1980's! As noted already by Ray and Fumbefingers, OED cannot be accurate or apply accurately to American English - "the end of the (19th) century" was definitely not in "the past 50 years". The Polish in "Czar" may have contributed to the "Cz" usage in the US, where a large Polish-American population had existed since the 19th century. That it's been changing here during the few decades since the Soviet collapse sent a new population of Russian immigrants our way is hardly surprising.

Answer (score -1):

The original pronunciation of Caesar was with a hard c, AE in Latin was pronounced as a long i, thus the German form Kaiser.  I believe wherever czar originated it was pronounced kuh-zar.  The Russians do not have a "ks" or "kz" sound but their alphabet does have a "ts" sound, thus tsar.

Comment: Ah! A man with a time machine! Excellent. I need you to run a few errands...

Comment: This is wrong on many accounts. 1) *Caesar* in Russian *(цезарь)* starts with a /ts/, just as *tsar (царь)* does. 2) Originally, it was *кесарь*. Stress on the first syllable, mind you. 3) *Kuh-zar* is not a valid pronunciation of *czar* in any Slavic language. 4) Russian does have /ks/, including as the onset *(ксантан, ксантиппа, Ксавер, ксерокс, Ксюша)*. 5) *Кз* is very rare, but possible as well. 6) Alphabets do not have sounds to begin with. They have letters. Which do not really correspond to sounds, or at all. 7) I am not sure what any of this has to do with the question at hand.