# Van Gogh goes or Van Gogh coughs? Is there a commonly accepted British English pronunciation?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, british-english

The question changed during the formulation from

> What is the correct 'British English' pronunciation of Van Gogh?

to

> ***Is there such a thing as a 'correct' English pronunciation of a Dutch
>   name -- specifically of Van Gogh?*** 
> Failing that, is there at least a
>   commonly accepted convention? For personal usage I'm interested in
>   'British English' variants including Irish English, but extra padding concerning US variants
>   would not go amiss.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincent_van_Gogh) gives the correct Dutch IPA pronunciation as  [ˈvɪnsɛnt ˈʋɪləm vɑŋ ˈɣɔx] and even has an [audio file](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/80/Vincent_willem_van_gogh.ogg) of same.

The solution might be to use the correct Dutch pronunciation, but it doesn't sit naturally with me. [This answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/210117/who-decides-how-a-foreign-name-should-be-transliterated-and-why-do-such-translit) on the ELU site made me think there might not be a definitive answer.

> Another consideration is that there is often no one established
>   “correct” pronunciation for foreign names in English. Usually for
>   famous or well-known people, some kind of conventional pronunciation
>   is established over time, but what that pronunciation will be is not
>   always predictable. Some people try to pronunce names as close to the
>   original language as they can. This means that it would be difficult
>   to figure out how to spell these names if it was based on how English
>   speakers pronounce them

---

Google wasn't as helpful as I thought it would be. Several sites gave the correct Dutch pronunciation and noted that English native speakers (both sides of the Atlantic) pronounced it incorrectly. But then I found [an ever so British perspective](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-B_GJCnZ8GEo/UjmVuCm2qBI/AAAAAAAAFAE/S2F4r_TFCd0/s1600/Vincent_Willem_van_Gogh_106+(600x446).jpg)

> Something that drives British people absolutely bonkers is hearing an
>   American "mispronounce" the name of Dutch post-impressionist Vincent
>   van Gogh. Pangs of rage fill up the collective consciousness as the
>   nation retorts in one voice: "it's VAN-GOFF, not VAN-GO!"

Though  not a big fan of the style of the piece, as an Irish English-speaker this is also the pronunciation I use.
So *can I assume in British and Irish English usage that Van Gogh rhymes with cough?*?

Comment: I suspect you're right. On a side note, there are many different ways the name can be pronounced in Dutch, as there are many different accents. In standard Dutch, it would be more like /xɔx/. In the south, where I believe he came from, it will be more like /ɣɔx/. A map of various Dutch dialects around the world, many of which are not even mutually comprehensible: https://external-preview.redd.it/mjmEC3s5UhFp7CvA_-PPCFcN1t3j2_br9zGbjVYjb4E.png?auto=webp&s=80f700928522e9cb5cf0b20a3e8bb6365aa75232 The number indicates the linguistic distance from standard Dutch.

Comment: Let it drive you crazy, but I've never heard anything other than "van go" on this side of the pond.  Occasionally it's pronounced with a slight throat-clearing "gh" sound at the end, but the sound is rarely emphasized.

Comment: @HotLicks: You haven't indicated which side.

Comment: @Cerberus - I'm on the same side as the crazy politicians, unfortunately.

Comment: FWIW, even after seeing a whole Doctor Who episode on Van Gogh, I can't recall the exact pronunciation used.

Comment: No, it doesn't rhyme with _cough_, because that word ends in /f/, and Van Gogh's name doesn't. You could devoice the initial /ɣ/ to /x/ and just make it /xox/; many Dutch speakers would.

Comment: @HorLicks - That could mean either side.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Have you really read the question?

Comment: @JohnLawler If Brits don't mind conflating a *Van Gogh course* with a *van golf course*, they shouldn’t mind Madrileñans pronouncing all those English *stop* signs as if they were *estofe* signs in a phonotactic Hail-Mary pass almost exactly paralleling this one.  Or maybe it’s Spanish revenge, trying to make the Brits cringe cuzza how Brits mangle the Spanish city of *Gijón* [xiˈχõŋ] into [ˈgɪd͡ʒən] —so as if it began with *git* from *Git out!* and then going on to rhyme with *pigeon*. Also better avoid riling them up about their *boxed Bachs* —if this keeps up it’s the *hoosegow* for sure!

Comment: @HotLicks Figures you'd be on the crazy pols’ side. Me, I oppose them. :)

Comment: To my ears the standard British pronunciation is more like Goch (to rhyme with loch) than Goff.

Comment: @Kate Bunting. Thanks for that. (And the rhyme works well as long as long as those speakers don't use the /lɒk/ pronunciation ;)) At first it made me think that theoretically at least Irish and Scottish speakers could be more disposed to using that pronunciation since the Irish language (compulsory at school) has that /x/ sound in it. For that matter Irish also has the /ɣ/ sound. But I was raised in Ireland and never heard it spoken the Dutch way in English. So much for speculation.

Comment: I've heard "go" and rhyming with "off" or "loch", even occasional attempts at the Dutch initial consonant. It's probable that different areas have different standard pronunciations (e.g. US vs UK, and possibly regions with /x/ will be more likely to use it), and possible that different institutions (museums, universities, etc) may have an informal standard.

Answer (score 3):

It may not be correct, but in my experience as a native south Londoner the name is pronounced GOFF. There's a recent meme showing the artist not being able to wear a face mask properly, as you see it hanging from his remaining ear.

This pronunciation has probably stuck due to its use in a lot of British humour. Consider this example:

The scene is the back yard of an art gallery. Two men come out of the gallery carrying boxes. Their delivery van has been driven away. "Where the van go?" asks one, "it's van goff, not van go you tart," says the other.

Comment: Another version of the joke that butchers even more artists' names: Did you hear about the poor art thieves' failed heist? They got caught in the getaway because they didn't have the Monet to buy Degas to make the Van Gogh.

Answer (score 3):

There's an interesting note on the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincent_van_Gogh):

> The
> pronunciation of Van Gogh varies in both English and Dutch. Especially in British English it is /ˌvæn ˈɡɒx/ or sometimes /ˌvæn ˈɡɒf/. American dictionaries list /ˌvæn ˈɡoʊ/, with a silent gh, as the most common pronunciation. In the dialect of Holland, it is [ˈvɪnsɛnt fɑŋˈxɔx], with a voiceless v and g. He grew up in Brabant and used Brabant dialect in his writing; his own pronunciation was thus likely [vɑɲˈʝɔç], with a voiced v and palatalised g and gh. In France, where much of his work was produced, it is [vɑ̃ ɡɔɡ(ə)].

I would have put this as a comment but it's too long and I didn't feel I should truncate it.

When I listened to the sound file file there, I was surprised it was **so** different from the 2 variants (*van go* and *van goff*) I've previously heard people debating.

I removed the cross-references from the quote but see original note at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincent_van_Gogh#cite_note-6

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best round-up I have found on this issue:

CNN, Emma Reynolds

> How do you pronounce "Van Gogh"? You're probably saying it wrong,
> according to insiders at the launch of an interactive exhibition on
> the artist in London. The "Meet Vincent van Gogh" experience on
> London's South Bank promises "breathtaking projections, interactive
> installations, state-of-the-art set-work and a compelling narrative"
> as it transports the viewer through the Dutch artist's life.
>
> But the audio guide for the installation, created by the Van Gogh
> Museum in Amsterdam, has raised a few eyebrows because it gives the
> artist's last name as "Van Go," the typical American pronunciation. In
> Britain, people tend to say "Van Gof."
>
> The guide's choice of "Van Go" sparked discussion at the news
> conference between the Dutch ambassador to the UK, Simon Smits;
> Adriaan Dönszelmann, managing director of the Van Gogh Museum; and the
> artist's great-grandnephew, Willem van Gogh.
>
> Martin Bailey, author of "Starry Night: Van Gogh at the Asylum," told
> CNN Style there are yet more variations on the name across the world
> -- and it even affected how the legendary artist signed his paintings. 10 most famous paintings in the world "There's an audio guide you go
> around with (at the London exhibition) and they pronounce it 'Go,' as
> they do in America," said Bailey, who writes a blog about Van Gogh for
> The Art Newspaper.
>
> "English people say 'Gof,' the French say 'Gog' and the Japanese say
> it differently, too. The Dutch pronounce it with a guttural sound --
> 'Khokh.'
>
> "It is always very difficult to know how to pronounce -- it's not easy
> for someone English or American, we just don't have that sound. Then
> it sounds pedantic if you insist on the Dutch pronunciation." Van Gogh
> regularly traveled around Europe, moving to London to work as an art
> dealer when he was 20, and living in France. His paintings are all
> simply signed "Vincent," and the artist is often named as Mr. Vincent
> or Monsieur Vincent in letters and documents. "He always wanted to be
> 'Vincent' because the French and English couldn't pronounce his name,"
> said Bailey.
>
> Two stolen Van Gogh paintings are finally returning to public view
> after 17 years In a letter to his brother Theo in March 1888, soon
> after Van Gogh moved to Arles in France, he explained that "in future
> my name must be put in the catalog the way I sign it on the canvases,
> i.e. Vincent and not Van Gogh, for the excellent reason that people
> here wouldn't be able to pronounce that name." The Van Gogh Museum has
> even created a video in which it asks visitors from across the world
> how they pronounce Van Gogh.
>
> So what are we to do if Van Gogh is simply too hard to say? Bailey has
> a suggestion. "I tend to do a slight fudge," he said. "Something
> between the English, French and Dutch."

```
              ---- *** -----
```

My advice is that if you can make the proper back-of-throat sound of that kh of the Dutch ending, please feel free to do so. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there such a thing as a 'correct' English pronunciation of a Dutch name -- specifically of Van Gogh?

This is one of the simpler questions. The convention is: **The correct pronunciation of anyone's name is the way that they pronounce it.**

There is no English, French, Russian, etc., pronunciation that can be described as "correct" - if it is not exactly as the owner of the name pronounces it then, regardless of the native language of the speaker, it is wrong or, at best, an approximation or a guess.

Comment: Can you add anything about the particular name here? How did Van Gogh pronounce it?

Comment: You'd lose a mark for spelling _Germany_ 'Deutschland' in an English essay, and probably for pronouncing 'Paris' the French way in an English oral test. You're choosing a subjective sense of 'correct'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You would certainly lose many marks for answering a question on pronunciation with remarks on spelling. Germans do not pronounce "Germany" as "Deutschland." -- *You're choosing a subjective sense of 'correct'.* On the contrary, I have given you the conventional and objective test for the "correct" pronunciation of any name: it can be tested against an absolutely correct source.

Comment: @Mitch The internet provides us with this: https://www.vangoghstudio.com/how-do-you-pronounce-van-gogh/

Comment: The link you've given states 'There is no right or wrong.' And also '
So did Van Gogh’s parents and his governess speak with a hard g in 1850 as they do in The Hague, Benschop and Kampen nowadays?

Probably.. not!' Or are you cherry-picking there too?

Comment: @Greybeard I'm just pointing out that you need to add to your text an actual answer to the OP's question, as opposed to commentary about pronunciation of names in general. If you add the link to your answer, make sure you also quote it too.

Answer (score -2):

As in loch. English-born , as opposed to Scottish-born,  people can learn to pronounce loch correctly with practice. As with any non native language speaker, sounds outside the native language have to be acquired with practice. Welsh presents the same problem for non native speakers.

Comment: How does this answer the question? It’s a pretty unclear question, but it seems to relate to usage rather than learning Dutch. A really trick question is how do the Dutch pronounce Hieronymus Bosch? Not the way it’s pronounced in either England or Scotland.

Comment: Fair comment. Most British people I know pronounce it as in Van Goch. Goff is based on English ‘cough’, although it might just as easily have been ‘bough’. Go is, I assume, from ‘though’. And same comment applies. I don’t speak Dutch, so can’t say about Bosch, other than admit I’ve always said Bosh!

Comment: — I agree. I have never heard anything other than Goch rhymes with loch, in England or Scotland. I’m not sure how the Dutch pronounce it, and certainly wouldn’t change if it’s different from how I do. I looked down my nose at the yanks when I first heard van Go, but the smugness was wiped off my face when I was corrected in the Netherlands for saying Bosh instead of (wait for it) Boss. It appears there was a sound change in the North Germanic sphere, and although modern Dutch spelling reflects this, the spelling of surnames, especially historical figures has been retained.

Comment: I shall endeavour  to remember it’s Boss! Thanks David.

Comment: — Add it to your store of useless information. I worked in The Netherlands for a couple of months which is why I know. I wouldn't dream of using standard British pronunciation at home though. I haven't checked out Van Gough, but the tricky thing in any case is the G sound. The Dutch for good day is "goede dag" which looks similar to the German (guten tag). Whereas the German is easy enough to approximate to, both g's in the Dutch are almost impossible. The first is something like a Y and the second a bit like the ch in loch. How they laughed at me!

Answer (score -3):

Pronunciation should be correct, and it should be understood by your peers. These can be opposing demands. Correct pronunciation is useless if nobody else knows what or who you are talking about. In the case of Dutch words, I would add that you should pronounce a word in such a way that saying it doesn't cause you damage.

Goch pronounced the same way that a Scottish person would pronounce Loch (Ness, for example) comes reasonably close to the correct way (although many Dutch people would disagree). It's definitely not like the gh in laugh or cough - but then lots of English people would have problems with the ch in Loch, so "van Gogh" with the same gh as in cough will be understood correctly by many.

If Americans say "Go" like the gh in "though", that's slightly worse than the English "Cough" in my opinion - no consonant is worse than the wrong one, and I bet they get the "O" wrong as well.

Comment: Are you saying that the Dutch damage themselves when they speak? How does that work exactly?

Comment: @tchrist The Dutch are trained from a very young age to produce certain sounds - hence they don't hurt themselves a lot when they do it. Asking foreigners to pronounce certain Dutch sounds is the linguistic equivalent of asking a normal grown-up to fold their legs behind their head; there are people that can do that without damaging themselves, but doesn't mean everybody should give it a go :)

Comment: @oerkelens it appears that with respect to R, Dutch children get a break [because of where the TV studios are located](https://youtu.be/7C8iwl2pNlQ). :)